# What is criteria of mining priority except for transaction-fee?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-selection, coin-age-priority, mastering-bitcoin

I am reading "Mastering Bitcoin written by Andreas" and I found this explanation of mining.

> Transactions are added to the new block, prioritized by the
>   highest-fee transactions first and a few other criteria.
>
> Source: [[Mastering Bitcoins: Mining Transactions in Blocks](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch02.html#_mining_transactions_in_blocks)]

I want to know what the a few other criteria are. And I want to see the source code where the system prioritizes by highest-fee transactions first and a few other criteria.

I guess that the code is in [`miner.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp). But I don't understand the exact line.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you're looking for is in [`CreateNewBlock`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0rc3/src/miner.cpp#L91).

The usual way transactions are added to a block is by sorting by priority. The priority of an input is the value being spent in the input multiplied by the number of confirmations it has. The priority of a transaction is the sum of all the priorities of the inputs. See [this line](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0rc3/src/miner.cpp#L197):

```
dPriority += (double)nValueIn * nConf;
```

Transactions are added to a [vector of transaction priority](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0rc3/src/miner.cpp#L146):

```
vector<TxPriority> vecPriority;
```

Then they are [sorted according to their priority](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0rc3/src/miner.cpp#L225-L226):

```
TxPriorityCompare comparer(fSortedByFee);
std::make_heap(vecPriority.begin(), vecPriority.end(), comparer);
```

And one by one, [transactions are verified to be valid and then added to the block](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0rc3/src/miner.cpp#L228-L286), done by order of priority, higher priority first.:

```
while (!vecPriority.empty())
...
// Added
pblock->vtx.push_back(tx);
```

Comment: ♦ As far as I read the code, if nBlockPrioritySize is set larger than 1, transaction fee has higher priority than the sum of all the priorities of the inputs. Is it correct?